# How to fix: An error has occurred while trusting the certificate: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied

Tags: ssl, .net-core, iis, localhost

I am developing a .net Core 7 API using Visual Studio. I enabled HttpsRedirection and all seemed fine, until I suddenly started getting this error from my browser: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

I tried the following command in CMD Administrator mode to trust the certificate:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust -v
```

The command produces the following output:

```
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.

[1] Listing certificates from CurrentUser\My

[2] Found certificates: 1 certificate

    1) DECC86D14FE509AFF72B64EE601B09D67F7558DC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-11-14 10:31:38Z to 2024-11-13 10:31:38Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[3] Checking certificates validity

[4] Valid certificates: 1 certificate

    1) DECC86D14FE509AFF72B64EE601B09D67F7558DC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-11-14 10:31:38Z to 2024-11-13 10:31:38Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[5] Invalid certificates: no certificates

[6] Finished listing certificates.

[1] Listing certificates from LocalMachine\My

[2] Found certificates: no certificates

[3] Checking certificates validity

[4] Valid certificates: no certificates

[5] Invalid certificates: no certificates

[6] Finished listing certificates.

[8] Filtered certificates: 1 certificate

    1) DECC86D14FE509AFF72B64EE601B09D67F7558DC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-11-14 10:31:38Z to 2024-11-13 10:31:38Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[9] Excluded certificates: no certificates

[14] Valid certificates: 1 certificate

    1) DECC86D14FE509AFF72B64EE601B09D67F7558DC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-11-14 10:31:38Z to 2024-11-13 10:31:38Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[15] Selected certificate: DECC86D14FE509AFF72B64EE601B09D67F7558DC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-11-14 10:31:38Z to 2024-11-13 10:31:38Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true

[29] Trusting the certificate to: DECC86D14FE509AFF72B64EE601B09D67F7558DC - CN=localhost - Valid from 2023-11-14 10:31:38Z to 2024-11-13 10:31:38Z - IsHttpsDevelopmentCertificate: true - IsExportable: true.

[45] Adding certificate to the trusted root certification authority store.

[31] An error has occurred while trusting the certificate: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StorePal.Add(ICertificatePal certificate)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Certificates.Generation.WindowsCertificateManager.TrustCertificateCore(X509Certificate2 certificate)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Certificates.Generation.CertificateManager.TrustCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate).

There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.
```

I am an administrator on the machine and have checked that I have full read/write access on the following folder:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

I have also tried to first clean the certs before trusting:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

I have also removed all localhost certificates from certlm.msc and recreated them successfully, however, when trying to trust the certificate the "Access Denied" error persists.

How can I fix / find more detail on the error?

Comment: Are you running the program as administrator?

Comment: @YurongDai yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found a workaround to bypass the certificate warning in every browser when accessing a Swagger URL. While this allows you to continue testing and development, it does not solve the underlying problem of trusting the development certificate system-wide on your machine.

Maybe you need to delete all localhost certificates with the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate friendly name manually because `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` did not delete all certificates.

Check the certificates in the certificate store. There should be a localhost certificate with the ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate friendly name both under `Current User > Personal > Certificates` and `Current User > Trusted root certification authorities > Certificates`.

Remove all the found certificates from both Personal and Trusted root certification authorities. Do not remove the IIS Express localhost certificate.

Then run the following commands:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Close any browser instances open. Open a new browser window to app.

More info in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#windows---certificate-not-trusted-1).

Answer (score -1):

I have gotten around the problem as follows:

- Enable Swagger on the API
- Open the API Swagger URL in the browser
- At this stage the browser prompts that there is a problem with the security certificate - click Continue to this website / Advanced > Proceed.

I had to do separately in each browser. I don't think it resolves the actual problem, but it is working for now!